# cube border is not connect

Tags: html, css

I require a 3D transform cube that my button can fit into it and flip left and right freely. now I find the css code to make this possible, however the border of cube is not connect with each other while I set ".cube" width below 200px. the problem is if I set the width 200px, the cube works great but the button is not fitting the size of cube face. Is it possible change CSS to make the cube a little smaller (say like width 170px) and mean while there's no gap/space between the border while flip the cube face ?

this is the site I do testing
https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/KRWjzm

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
var radioGroup = document.querySelector('.radio-group');
var currentClass = '';

function changeSide() {
  var checkedRadio = radioGroup.querySelector(':checked');
  var showClass = 'show-' + checkedRadio.value;
  if ( currentClass ) {
    cube.classList.remove( currentClass );
  }
  cube.classList.add( showClass );
  currentClass = showClass;
}
// set initial side
changeSide();

radioGroup.addEventListener( 'change', changeSide );
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.scene {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 80px;
  perspective: 400px;
}

.cube {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.cube.show-front  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(   0deg); }
.cube.show-right  { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY( -90deg); }
.cube.show-back   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(-180deg); }
.cube.show-left   { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateY(  90deg); }
.cube.show-top    { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX( -90deg); }
.cube.show-bottom { transform: translateZ(-100px) rotateX(  90deg); }

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.cube__face--front  { background: hsla(  0, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--right  { background: hsla( 60, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--back   { background: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--left   { background: hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--top    { background: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--bottom { background: hsla(300, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }

.cube__face--front  { transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--right  { transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--back   { transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--left   { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--top    { transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(100px); }
.cube__face--bottom { transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(100px); }

label { margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--back">back</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--right">right</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--left">left</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--top">top</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="radio-group">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="front" checked /> front
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="right" /> right
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="back" /> back
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="left" /> left
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="top" /> top
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="bottom" /> bottom
  </label>
</p>
```

Comment: if you set `.cube` width below 200px you have to take the half of the width and edit the `.cube.show-` and `.cube__face--`

Comment: check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0o3skzc2/)

Comment: thank you xmaster for your quick answer and now it works like a charm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the `width` of the face of the cube, you have to change `translateZ()` as well.

`translateZ()` has to be equal to **half of the width of the cube's face**.

#### See working demo below:

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
var radioGroup = document.querySelector('.radio-group');
var currentClass = '';

function changeSide() {
  var checkedRadio = radioGroup.querySelector(':checked');
  var showClass = 'show-' + checkedRadio.value;
  if ( currentClass ) {
    cube.classList.remove( currentClass );
  }
  cube.classList.add( showClass );
  currentClass = showClass;
}
// set initial side
changeSide();

radioGroup.addEventListener( 'change', changeSide );
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

.scene {
  width: 170px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  margin: 80px;
  perspective: 400px;
}

.cube {
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: translateZ(-100px);
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.cube.show-front  { transform: translateZ(-85px) rotateY(   0deg); }
.cube.show-right  { transform: translateZ(-85px) rotateY( -90deg); }
.cube.show-back   { transform: translateZ(-85px) rotateY(-180deg); }
.cube.show-left   { transform: translateZ(-85px) rotateY(  90deg); }
.cube.show-top    { transform: translateZ(-85px) rotateX( -90deg); }
.cube.show-bottom { transform: translateZ(-85px) rotateX(  90deg); }

.cube__face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  line-height: 170px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.cube__face--front  { background: hsla(  0, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--right  { background: hsla( 60, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--back   { background: hsla(120, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--left   { background: hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--top    { background: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }
.cube__face--bottom { background: hsla(300, 100%, 50%, 0.7); }

.cube__face--front  { transform: rotateY(  0deg) translateZ(85px); }
.cube__face--right  { transform: rotateY( 90deg) translateZ(85px); }
.cube__face--back   { transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(85px); }
.cube__face--left   { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(85px); }
.cube__face--top    { transform: rotateX( 90deg) translateZ(85px); }
.cube__face--bottom { transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(85px); }

label { margin-right: 10px; }
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--front">front</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--back">back</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--right">right</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--left">left</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--top">top</div>
    <div class="cube__face cube__face--bottom">bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p class="radio-group">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="front" checked /> front
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="right" /> right
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="back" /> back
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="left" /> left
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="top" /> top
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="rotate-cube-side" value="bottom" /> bottom
  </label>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you @user9408899 ! yes I now realize how it works. thank you for point it out ! it works for me now !